# Gitlab is not closing issues I reference through a commit

Tags: commit, gitlab, issue-tracking

Gitlab doesn't close issues I created and then closed in a commit.

I'm using GitLab 7.2.1 ff1633f and the following commits have been tried:

- Closes (#1)
- Closes[#1]
- Closes #1
- Fixes[#1]
- Fixes (#1)
- Fixes #1
- Fixes issue #1

I have no clue where the error might be, for asfar as I can see, there are no errors, commits just neatly get into Gitlab, it all works, I even can click the issue number in commits, but it just doesn't close them.

What is the problem here?

Comment: In the server I use it can take up to 20 minutes until the issue appears as Closed

Comment: A possible explanation is that you're making the push to the default branch. Or you're not merging to the default branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a bug, possible duplicate of: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8063 Now nuked by GitLab with all other GitHub issues, and has no Wayback Machine archive either. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/394 seems related.

I recommend always looking there first for things that look like bugs.

Comment: page not found
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8063

Comment: @Sam companies are unable to not break links, I keep forgetting. And no Wayback Machine link either :-(